# Get user theme directly in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In lightning, is there a way / global event that we can directly get user ui themeDisplayed without calling an apex method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of today (and as far as I know of), there's no direct way of getting the UI Theme in a Lightning Component without implementing a server side controller.

The Salesforce Developers Blog on the topic [Introducing UI Theme Detection for Lightning Experience](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2016/04/introducing-ui-theme-detection-for-lightning-experience.html) mentions this, excerpt below:

> You can’t determine the user’s UI theme directly within a Lightning Component because it only has access to a limited set of global values. You must implement an Apex server-side controller to provide this information.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend it, but you *could* look through the DOM for the **data-aura-rendered-by** property.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-aura-rendered-by]');
```

If you find it, you're in Lightning Experience.

While I don't think it's too likely, there's no guarantee this won't change someday, so...be ready for your code to break during some future release!

I would **always** use an Apex controller instead, caching the response to lighten the load.

```
String theme = UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed();
```

More info, including working sample code here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2016/04/introducing-ui-theme-detection-for-lightning-experience.html